# Can Resharper extract parameters in a custom way?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Im using the latest R# version.

Looking at this method signature :

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Register(string UserName, string OrgPassword, string NewPassword, int QuestionID, int QuestionLanguageID, string QuestionAnswer, int MasterEntityID, string ua)
{
}
```

I can do  :

[image]

Which will create :

[image]

Where :

```
public class RegisterParams
{
    string _userName;
    string _orgPassword;
   //...

    public RegisterParams(string UserName, string OrgPassword, string NewPassword, int QuestionID, int QuestionLanguageID, string QuestionAnswer, int MasterEntityID, string ua)
    {
        _userName = UserName;
        _orgPassword = OrgPassword;
        //...
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
    }
   //...
```

But I *don't* want this structure.

I want to create my own structure :

```
 public class RegisterParams
    {
     public string UserName{ get;set;}
     public string OrgPassword{ get;set;}
    //...
  }
```

**Question:**

Does Resharper expose in its template explorer this kind of *"do something with what is selected"*   ?

Nb I know that there is a `$SELECTION$` token but how can I split those and create my own structure ?

Comment: Sorry, the only way to do it in a custom way is to write your own equivalent refactoring.